# How to Retrieve the AndroidManifest.xml file ?

Tags: android

When I am doing the project editing works, I have deleted the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Is any   way to recover the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Try selecting the folder and hitting F5, and check the Navigator view.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help - that did it.  I hadnt seen the Refresh option up til now.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy/paste it into the project.

Answer (score 1):

Open another Android project then copy and paste the AndroidManifest.xml file. It will work perfectly.